# Create a dialog inside a palette

Tags: user-interface, dialog-window, palettes

I am trying to get better at UI programming, by building a simple greeting.

The user is asked to type his name in a prompt, and Mathematica will then print a greeting using his name:

> What is your name? Doe
>
> Hello, Doe, nice to meet you!

I want this interaction to take place inside a window of its self. I think that a palette is suitable here.

This is a time lapse of what I want to program:

[image: screenshots]

I am new to this concept of UI, so I think that a first objective for me would be to insert a dialogue box into the palette.

How do I do that?

I tried

```mathematica
CreatePalette[Input["What is your name?"]
 , WindowSize -> {400, 300}, WindowTitle -> "Hello!", 
 Saveable -> False]
```

But this rather produces a self dialog window, which its returned value is inserted into the palette.

- The idea for this exercise is taken from Brian Hogan's book [Exercises for Programmers](https://pragprog.com/titles/bhwb/exercises-for-programmers/).